# Mi python redondea a cero

Tags: python, python-2.7

Cuando hago cálculos en python (ejecutando en Jupyter Notebook) obtengo cosas raras:

```py
8/9=0
```

Se puede hacer algo con la configuración de python para arreglar ese problema? Ya he usado `round()` pero es el mismo resultado, es con python 2.7 que uso en mi trabajo.

Comment: En el sitio en inglés, parecen explicar el problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/integer-division-in-python-2-and-python-3

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevaba días peleando con eso jaja :) salvaste el día.

Comment: De nada compañero! c:

Comment: Si puedes, cambiate a Python3. En el momento en que escribo esto (julio 2022), la versión 2 ha dejado de estar soportada desde hace más de dos años (y hace más de 8 años que habían avisado de esto y recomendado a todo el mundo que cambiase a Python3).

Comment: En mi computadora personal tengo python 3, pero en el trabajo no me lo dan :( jajajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python 2.x debes asegurarte de tener al menos uno de los operadores de la división de tipo float. Lo siguiente  funciona para mi:

**a)**

```
8 / float(9)
```

**b)**

```
float(8)/ float(9)
```

**c)**

```
float(8)/ 9
```